# How to focus the view in the middle of a wrapper?

Tags: html, css

[Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sm6Y.jpg)

I'm wondering how I can display the middle of a wrapper that is larger than the viewport of any device (here it's a mobile phone for example), but also make it scrollable on x and y.

I tried this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quarter first">
        <div class="theme">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter second">
        <div class="theme">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter third">
        <div class="theme">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter fourth">
        <div class="theme">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.wrapper {width: 200vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.quarter {width: calc(100% / 2);
    height: calc(100% / 2);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.first {background-color: aqua;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
}

.second {background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    right: 25%;
}

.third {background-color: greenyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -25%;
}

.fourth {background-color: rosybrown;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I know the values make nonsense, but I just wanted to see if the top left part would be scrollable. It is not.

Then I tried a trick with the background positions, but the content of each quarter will not be displayed correctly.

```
.wrapper {width: 200vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.quarter {width: calc(100% / 2);
    height: calc(100% / 2);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.first {background-color: aqua;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -50%;
}

.second {background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.third {background-color: greenyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.fourth {background-color: rosybrown;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Thanks for your answers <3

Comment: I don't understand what do you expecte ?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't really know how to explain it...

I have a wrapper that's for example 200 view width. And the first quarter take the half of it, 100vw. So it will be displayed over all the width of the device. But on the screen, I want to see the half of the first quarter, and the half of the second, and the other part will be scrollable.

I hope I had explain it a bit better...

Comment: but if your first quarter is set to 100vw, you can't only display the half of it ? maybe you have an example of website